# procedure "system" can't find and execute program

Tags: c++

i want program to execute the path including programm(.exe).Also, i have spaces in user name.

so that, i made that script in c++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path current_path = std::filesystem::current_path();
    std::cout << "called from origin file!" << std::endl;

    std::string string_current_path = current_path.u8string();
    string_current_path = string_current_path + "\\print.exe";

    string_current_path = std::string(string_current_path);
    const char * command = string_current_path.c_str();

    std::cout <<command<< std::endl;
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

procedure "system" is able to gain only const char* variable, so i convert path to string and after that i convert this into const char* to make it able to be there. But, it doesn't work.

output:

```
called from origin file!
C:\Users\Nair PC\Desktop\innerfall(versionV2)\print.exe
"C:\Users\Nair" is not valid member of command or executing programm
```

Comment: maybe you need to quote the path, `string_current_path = "\"" + string_current_path + "\""`

Comment: So, what is the output? And what is the path to the executable you want to run? BTW: There's quite a bunch of code there that could be improved. Consider submitting it to codereview.stackexchange.com, do check their site guidelines first though!

Comment: path is C:\Users\Nair PC\Desktop\innerfall(versionV2)

Comment: it says the file cant find of path: C:\Users\Nair

Comment: The part that has `Nair PC` has a space in it.  You'll need to escape that space, or surround the parameter in quotes.

Comment: but the full path is C:\Users\Nair PC\Desktop\innerfall(versionV2)\print.exe

Comment: can i keep spaces? Or should i remove it?

Comment: @Nair You need to quote the path containing the spaces. This has now been explained three times, and the first comment even has code to show you how to do it.

Comment: @Nair What do you think this line of code is doing `string_current_path = std::string(string_current_path);`? Since `string_current_path` is a string already you don't need to convert it to one. Just remove that line.

Comment: @Nair Although you don't need to remove the spaces from your path, it is good general adivce not to create directories with spaces or brackets in their name. It's just one more thing that might cause problems. Programming is hard enough as it is without adding gratuitous difficulties.

Comment: i made std::string() to keep it safe as linker can make mistakes

Comment: @Nair It doesn't make mistakes.

Comment: You will encounter the same message if you enter `C:\Users\Nair PC\Desktop\innerfall(versionV2)\print.exe` in your terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `operator<<` of `std::filesystem::path` to write a path to a `std::stringstream` and then convert it back to a `std::string` - it will return quoted path, so no issues if spaces are there in path.

Also, to append `print.exe` to `current_path`, just use `operator/=` of `std::filesystem::path`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path current_path = std::filesystem::current_path();
    current_path /= "print.exe";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << current_path;

    std::string command_str = ss.str();
    std::cout << command_str.c_str() << '\n';
    system(command_str.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is here! i found this one!

fixed script:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path current_path = std::filesystem::current_path();
    std::wcout << L"called from origin file!" << std::endl;

    std::filesystem::path exe_path = current_path / L"print.exe";
    std::wstring command = L"\"" + exe_path.wstring() + L"\"";

    _wsystem(command.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact that you put quotes around it, solves your issue. Switching to wide strings is not needed.